# Is it possible to detect NaN without using isNaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

Can I write a isNan() function with JavaScript? Can JavaScript check for sure that a variable is `NaN` without native `isNaN` function?

This is a interview question.

Comment: Yes. What property does `NaN` have when used in equality? <-- Consider this a prompt from a nice interviewer :-)

Comment: @pst `a = NaN`

`typeof a`
=>`"number"`
`!!a`
=>`false`
`b = 0`
`typeof b`
=>`"number"`
`!!b`
=>`false`

Comment: True enough .. but there are no equality operators (e.g. `==`) used there. The equality expression I am thinking of would *normally* be considered a *tautology*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is a number, and is not equal to itself, it is NaN.

Note: As @pst has pointed out, the number constraint is unnecessary. `NaN` appears to be the only value in JS != itself.

Comment: @pst Objects aren't equal to identical objects, (at least in as much as the `==` operator is concerned).

Comment: @pst Yeah I meant identical objects, not the same one. You're right though, updated the answer.

Comment: @Shmiddty `console.assert()` is useful in cases like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution for this question:

```
var is_NaN = function(n) {

  return (n !== n);  
}

is_NaN(1/'a'); // true
isNaN(1/'a'); // true
```

Because in JavaScript `NaN` isn't equal to itself. An expression `NaN === NaN` always returns `false`

The second solution:

You can use built-in `isFinite` function. `isFinite` checks whether the input is a number that is **neither** `Infinity` **nor** `NaN`.

```
isFinite(NaN) // false
isFinite(Infinity) // false
isFinite(1) // true
isFinite(true) // true, because argument true is equal to 1
isFinite('a') // false
isFinite(1/'a') // false
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12012003)

Answer (score -1):

ECMA 6

```
Number.isNaN(42) === false
Number.isNaN(NaN) === true
```

http://es6-features.org/#NumberTypeChecking